# Is this proposition true or false?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

This is Apostol calculus chapter 10.24 exercise 21.

Let $$f:[1,\infty)\to \mathbb R$$ such that $$\exists I_{n}=\int_{1}^{n}f(x)dx \forall n\in \mathbb N$$If $$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0; \lim_{n\to \infty}I_{n}=A$$ then $$\Rightarrow \int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx=A$$

I just want you to tell me if this proposition is true or false, My classmate told me is false but I cant find a counterexample, I would appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true.  The difference between the  integral and the closest $I_n$ is bounded by the maximum of $|f(x)|$ in the interval of length $\frac 12$.  It would not be true if you didn't have $f(x) \to 0$.  You could have $f(x)=\sin (2\pi x)$, where all the $I_n$ are $0$, but the integral oscillates and has no limit.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! and one last question instead of having $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$ as hypothesis we have that $f>0$ will this also holds true?

Comment: Yes, because $f \gt 0$ implies $f \to 0$-Since the $I_n$ approach a limit, the differences between them approaches zero and you can't have the cancellation of my $\sin$ example.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! I will try formally prove this :D